# Cuenta Regresiva con DataTables

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

Tengo la siguiente problema.
Tengo una funcion que realiza una cuenta regresiva. Por el momento, la tengo estatica, pero el valor vendra de una consulta a la bd para calcular la fecha de hoy y compararla con la fecha a restar.
Esta es la funcion:

```
function faltan() {
    var futuro = new Date(2018, 07, 14, 22, 40);
    var actualiza = 1000;
    var ahora = new Date();
    var faltan = futuro - ahora;
    // si todavís no es futuro
    if (faltan > 0) {
        var segundos = Math.round(faltan / 1000);
        var minutos = Math.floor(segundos / 60);
        var segundos_s = segundos % 60;
        var horas = Math.floor(minutos / 60);
        var minutos_s = minutos % 60;
        var dias = Math.floor(horas / 24);
        var horas_s = horas % 24;
        // escribe los resultados
        (segundos_s < 10) ? segundos_s = "0" + segundos_s : segundos_s = segundos_s;
        (minutos_s < 10) ? minutos_s = "0" + minutos_s : minutos_s = minutos_s;
        (horas_s < 10) ? horas_s = "0" + horas_s : horas_s = horas_s;
        (dias < 10) ? dias = "0" + dias : dias = dias;
        var resultado = dias+ ":" + horas_s + ":" + minutos_s + ":" + segundos_s;
        //document.formulario.reloj.value = resultado;
        document.formulario.reloj.value = resultado;
        //actualiza el contador
        setTimeout("faltan()", actualiza);
    }
    // estamos en el futuro
    else {
        //document.formulario.reloj.value = "00 dias : 00 horas : 00 minutos : 00 segundos";
        document.formulario.reloj.value = "Tiempo Expirado";
    }
}
```

esa funcion calcula el tiempo restante en dias, horas, minutos y segundos.
La variable futuro (var futuro), es la que contendra el valor extraido desde la BD.
Esto es donde se muestra en la tabla generada en datatables:

```
{
"sClass": "alignRight",
"data" : null,
'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
 return "<form name='formulario'><input type='text' name='reloj' size='10' style='border : 0px ; text-align : center'>"
 "</form>";
}
}
```

El problema que tengo, es como declarar la variable futuro (var futuro) dentro de datatables para poder usarla luego en la funcion que me calculara el tiempo restante. cabe señalar que los valores que vendran de la BD, es en formato YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS.

Si falta informacion, con gusto la proporcionare.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda y/u orientacion al respecto.
Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pasar valores de php a js te toca asi:

```
var JSONdata    = JSON.parse(data); //parsea la informacion
var futuro = JSONdata[0].fecha_BD; //obtener el valor que necesitas
```

**Nota:** tener cuidado con el formato que llegue desde la BD para hacer la comparacion...

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. no necesito pasar de php a js. lo que necesito es tomar la el dato que viene por json e insertarlo en la variable futuro pero dentro de datatables.

Comment: bueno, entonces poner `data.el_campo` o depende de como envie el json

Comment: @maha1982 siendo asi, entonces ahi modificque la respuesta, mira asi

Comment: gracias por tu informacion. Consulta, como usar luego esa variable futuro, fuera el datatables para usarla en la funcion que realiza el contador?

Comment: entonces debes declararla por fuera, para que su ambito sea mas global y no local, me alegro si te sirvio la puedes marcar como valida XD

Comment: como podria declarar esa variable global (var futuro), la declaro dentro del datatables y luego la uso en la funcion? te agradeceria me orientes. muchas gracias

Comment: declaralas las varaible global fuera de las funciones y de la tabla

Comment: funciona excelente amigo. muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo.. un saludo

Comment: De nada bro, siempre en un placer ayudar...